# Zend Framework: How to set _one_ default error handler for all modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling

I created several modules. And added follow options in application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.class = Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.module = default
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.controller = error
resources.frontController.plugins.ErrorHandler.options.action = error
```

Everything was working until I set up modules.

I added resources.modules[] = "" in application.ini to make the model work. And added boostrap for each module.

After that the default error handler doesn't work. And zend requires the modules' error handler.
If I delete the option resources.modules[] = "" then it works again.

I tried to place option resources.modules[] = "" after and befor overhead options, but the result is the same.

Comment: Why would you want to manually register `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler`? It gets registered automatically by `Zend_Controller_Front`.

Comment: Because if I dont register this manually then ZF requires errorController for each module. And as a result I have several errorControllers in application.

Answer (score 4):

Have you set your module directory correctly? Like this:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
```

And in your bootstrap, you ought to have something like the following:

```
protected function _initModules()
{
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->addModuleDirectory('../application/modules');
}
```

Those pieces of code made my global error controller function correctly, across all modules.